# Should I use "plugin:vue/essential" AND "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended" when linting?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, lint

The documentation is unclear. If I am using Vue3 do I need both or just `plugin:vue/vue3-recommended`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because essential is subset of recommended, using recommended rules mean you don't need to use essential rules. Please give a look at [this doc on vue3 rules](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/). it describes what each rule cover.

```
base rule
essential: base + essential
strongly-recommended: base + essential + strongly-recommended
recommended: base + essential + strongly-recommended + recommended
```

Edit: I'll make the answer clear. *recommended is superset of essential*

[below is the extract from this vue official doc](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#usage)

it's described in official document as...

> "plugin:vue/base" ... Settings and rules to enable correct ESLint parsing.

> "plugin:vue/vue3-essential" ... `base`, plus rules to prevent errors or unintended behavior.

> "plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended" ... Above, plus rules to considerably improve code readability and/or dev experience.

> "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended" ... Above, plus rules to enforce subjective community defaults to ensure consistency.

Comment: Is the answer that "recommended" is a superset of "base", and so the OP doesn't need both?

Comment: in short: he doesn't need both. but he can still have both if he wants to.

Comment: That might make a better first sentence for this answer.  Maybe also clarify if one is the superset of the other (in which case, having both would be harmless and wrong).

Comment: thanks for the opinion. I've revised the answer as you suggested.